# A way to resolve the time of packet created in socket tcp

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am using socket TCP in C#.

Here is some code:

System.Net.Sockets.Socket clientSocket;

...

```
clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

...
clientSocket.Receive( ...)
```

The clientSocket object receive data - There is a created packet on the server side, which decide when sending it.

Is there any way to retrieve the date+time the packet was sent and when it was created?

Also, is there any way to retrieve the date+time when using protocol such as REST?

Need some sample code, please.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you control the contents of the packet, include the date and time in the packet itself. If you don't, any solution will be probably overkill and low level. And you'll get a time extremely similar to the time of reception, and somehow meaningless as it comes (or may come) from another clock in another computer.

Comment: I don't control the packet contents. I think that there is very basic inplementation that I can resolve what is behind that packet including timestamps. That's some basics of the protocol which encode the packet and decode it to a readable buffet. When decoding there is checksum byte and some extra data which can be figured out, but how can I resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the protocol running over TCP that will determine whether you will be able to determine such date time information. You will need to interpret the block of bytes returned by Receive() as per the protocol you are interested in.

For example code see this tutorial:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c8781/Asynchronous-Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-II.htm

REST isnt a protocol.
RESTful apis don't typically contain a date+time each message was sent unless someone has designed that into their API.